# PDFBox add background when creating document

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

So I want to not only add text to a pdf when I create it but as well add a background image at the same time. I was wondering if this is possible since I haven't been able to find any example and the only question similar to this ([This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33406920/how-to-add-background-image-to-pdf-using-pdfbox)) has not given any feedback from the person that made the question and it wasn't marked as solved.

I'm using this very simple example at the moment:

```
       PDDocument doc = null;
       PDPage page = null;

       try{
           doc = new PDDocument();
           page = new PDPage();

           doc.addPage(page);
           PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;

           PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
           content.beginText();
           content.setFont( font, 12 );
           content.moveTextPositionByAmount( 100, 700 );
           content.drawString("Hello World");

           content.endText();
           content.close();
           doc.save("printme.pdf");
           doc.close();
       } catch (Exception e){
           System.out.println(e);
       }
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929954/watermarking-with-pdfbox

Comment: @0x594f4c4f203b29 That is a pretty smart solution, first generate the text and then set the image as background, if you put it as a solution I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: @user3272243 you can upvote the linked solution, if that one is your favorite. IMHO the one here is better, as the linked one applies to existing PDF files and you're searching something for newly created files.

Comment: @user3272243 thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_A4);
        document.addPage(page);
        PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;
        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, true, true);
        addImageToPage(document, 0, 0, 4f, "D:/test.jpg", contentStream);
        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.setFont(font, 12);
        contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(100, 700);
        contentStream.drawString("Hello World");
        contentStream.endText();
        contentStream.close();
        document.save("D:/mydoc.pdf");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

method to add image :

```
public static void addImageToPage(PDDocument document, int x, int y, float scale, String imageFilePath, PDPageContentStream contentStream)
        throws IOException {
    BufferedImage tmp_image = ImageIO.read(new File(imageFilePath));
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(tmp_image.getWidth(), tmp_image.getHeight(),
            BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
    image.createGraphics().drawRenderedImage(tmp_image, null);
    PDXObjectImage ximage = new PDPixelMap(document, image);
    contentStream.drawXObject(ximage, x, y, ximage.getWidth() * scale, ximage.getHeight() * scale);
}
```

Comment: Why do you add the image AFTER the text? Unless the image does have transparency, you're overwriting the text.

Comment: made required changes. now working fine.